# How to Prevent/Remove [External] from Appearing on Office/Microsoft 365 Emails on Subject Line

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have access to our Office 365 / Microsoft 365 admin portal.

Some emails appear prefixed with `[External]` on the subject line. This prefix causes issues, and I have been asked to remove that.

How do I configure the Admin Portal to NOT prefix emails from some emails with `[External]`?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I configure the Admin Portal to NOT prefix emails from some emails with [External]?

You will need to remove the prepend action, for the Exchange Transport Rule, that governs emails that are received outside of your organization.  **You can simply remove the action that prepends text to the subject line when the email is outside of your organization.**

> [image]

Source: [Marking External Email with an Exchange Transport Rule](https://office365itpros.com/2019/03/08/marking-external-email-with-exchange-transport-rule/)

Comment: Since this requires you to be an Administrator to modify the rule, and I expect that Administrator to be aware of the Office 365 administrator panel, I am not going to provide step by step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Microsoft 365 support. I attempted to locate above and only saw how I can apply rules, which I did not. I had no rules.

The short story is that an email sent from here yielded `[External] XXXXX` on the subject line at the recipient's inbox, not our inbox. That `[External]` tag caused issues at the recipient end, as it got flagged as a potential phishing email.

I thought the external tag was at our end, not their end.

The solution is that the problem is not our problem, but THEIR problem. The recipient has to have their admin add an exception for our user or our domain or simply have their admin delete the rule.

I would think that the recipient should have known that, as they had the rule set up, not me. I never heard of the external tag before today, and yet I solved their problem. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Prepending [External] to the email subject can be configured/customized through mailbox rules.

> I thought the external tag was at our end, not their end.

For this case, you can try external email tagging. It has many advantages over traditional mailflow rules. For eg, External tag will appear only in your end, it won't take a lot of space in the subject line, etc.

You can enable external email tagging through PowerShell. Check this article for more info: https://blog.admindroid.com/protect-o365-from-phishing-attack-using-external-email-tagging/

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this with Exchange Online PowerShell Module using the command:

```
Set-ExternalInOutlook -Enabled $false
```

This is the only way to disable it.  You can't do it through the admin center.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).