# "This email is from an external mail server etc." <- can I get rid of this?

Tags: email, thunderbird, office365, spam-prevention, mail-server

On many (but not all) of my incoming email messages, I see a message saying:

> This email is from an external mail server, be judicious when opening attachments or link

My mail server is - unfortunately - outlook.office365.com . I'm thinking it might be the culprit rather than my correspondents themselves, although I can't quite tell.

Anyway, this is super annoying, and basically meaningless. I mean, of course most email comes from an "external mail server" - not everyone on the planet uses the same server after all.

My question:

1. Why am I even getting these notices?
2. Other than "scrub" them ex-post-facto from the displayed message (e.g. with a Thunderbird extension) - is there something I can do to avoid getting them?

Comment: This is configured by an Administrator on the Exchange side.  Microsoft Exchange has the ability to generate this particular message when it detects an email outside of your organization.  Are you that Administrator?

Comment: I have already answered this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1552946/how-to-prevent-remove-external-from-appearing-on-office-microsoft-365-emails-o/1552950#1552950)

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm about the opposite thing of an administrator... :-(

Comment: I don't have the required environment to provide detailed screenshots, but as you can see from my answer to the potential duplicate, the message is generated and configured within the Admin Portal, which means it can only be changed by an Administrator.

Comment: Is your Office 365 account part of an organisation or a personal account?

Comment: @Mokubai: It's an organizational account. My old university.

Comment: Then as mentioned by Ramhound you need to contact your organisational administrator to remove or amend the notices.

Comment: @Mokubai: Fair enough. I'll try that. However - let's suppose they don't agree (after all, why would they care about an ex-ajunct-staff-member complaining?) Is there no other course of action?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this message is coming from the sender's side and there is nothing
you can do except scrubbing it out on your side.

It seems to me that the sender is situated within a corporate email system,
but has decided to configure his own email server which is external to the
corporate network, rather than using the corporate server.
The corporate email software has then added this warning to each email sent
by that user.

You may verify my theory by making a list of the sources of these messages,
to see if they have a common source(s).

You may see examples for such configurations for
[Broadcom](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/content/broadcom/techdocs/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/layer7-api-management/api-developer-portal/4-2/install-configure-and-upgrade/configure-and-use-external-mail-server.html)
and
[Plesk](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/customer-guide/mail-settings/using-external-mail-servers-such-as-gmail.74086/)
(although I don't know if their servers add such a warning message).

Answer (score 0):

If it is outlook that is the reason, someone (some admin in your organisation?) put it there. It should not be the default, though defaults might have changed since I last looked.

If you have admin app access in your 365 account,

- select admin app
- admin centers -> exchange
- select mail flow

There you should be able to alter the rules; if it's Outlook giving you this message, there should be a rule for it there.